# Secure pseudo-random generator

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, security-definition

> Suppose that $G : \{0,1\}^k \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{2k}$ is a secure pseudo-random generator. Describe what is wrong with each of the following attempts to build a pseudo-random generator with $k$-bit seeds and $4k$-bit outputs: (Here $s$ is seeds and $\mathbin\|$ means concatenate)
>
> 1) $G_1(s) = G(s) \mathbin\| G(0^{k})$
>
> 2) $G_2(s) = G(s) \mathbin\| G(r)$ where $r$ is a fresh random $k$-bit value;
>
> 3) $G_3(s) = G(s) \mathbin\| (G(s)  \oplus 1^{2k})$
>
> 4) $G_4(s_{L} \mathbin\| s_{R}) = G(s_{L} \mathbin\| s_{R}) \,\mathbin\|\, G(s_{R} \mathbin\| s_{L})$  where $|s_{L}| = |s_{R}| = \frac{k}{2}$;
>
> 5) $G_5(s_{L} \mathbin\| s_{R}) = G(s_{L} \mathbin\| 0^{ k \over 2}) \,\mathbin\|\, G(0^{k \over 2} \mathbin\| s_{R})$  where $|s_{L}| = |s_{R}| = \frac{k}{2}$.

This is kind of homework and discussion problem. I am not sure how or where to start with each. I just have idea of checking there exists PPT distinguisher D there is larger negotiable value. So it can't be a pseudo-random generator. Point me in the right direction of proof (any hint) would be helpful.

Comment: So $k$ should be even, for 4 and 5 to be well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for $G_2$ does not even define a function (will give different output for the same seed at different invocations).

The second half of $G_1(s)$ is constant, not very random, is it?

$G_3(s)$ can also be easily distinguished from random as its second half is the bitwise complement of the first half.

Comment: "Compare $G_4(s)$ and $G_4(\overline{s})$ where the second input is $s$ with halves swapped." That by itself is not necessarily a problem. In the standard definition of a PRG you see only a single output of the PRG and have no influence on the input.

Comment: @Maeher you have to see more, or how can you compare the distributions?

Comment: You don't. Check standard definitions for pseudorandom generators.  See for example [Definition 3.14](https://books.google.com/books?id=OWZYBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PR2&dq=modern%20cryptography&pg=PA62#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Introduction to Modern Cryptography. A distinguisher needs to distinguish the output of the PRG from a truly random string with non-negligible probability.

Comment: @Maeher and the adversary chooses inputs?

Comment: No, check the definition. The input is chosen uniformly at random. If the adversary would choose the input, distinguishing would be trivial.

Comment: The link was inaccessible, other source? @Maeher

Comment: You can also check Goldreich's Foundations of Cryptography  Volume 1. But you'll have to combine Definitions 3.8,3.7 and 3.2 to see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

For $G_1$ and $G_3$ it should be fairly easy to give a distinguisher, where you just have to analyze its success probability in the two cases.

As Henno already stated, $G_2$ simply does not fulfill the definition of a PRG.

For $G_4$ and $G_5$ it is helpful to instantiate the construction with some specific PRG which you construct based on another PRG (you also have to prove that your construction actually is a PRG, usually by reduction). Then you show that this allows you to construct a distinguisher. Hint: try to instantiate it with a PRG that leaks 1 or 2 bits of the seed to its output.